# Laptop wont boot windows unless put it there in BIOS or DOS for 15-20 minutes

Tags: boot, bios, bsod

I have this strange problem where my Toshiba Laptop(A505 s6960) restarts or BSOD if it is not put in BIOS or DOS for at least 20 minutes. Once this time is given in BIOS or DOS, laptop works smoothly for hours till it is turned off. Laptop battery is dead and I removed it 1-2 years ago.

I tried things like replacing RAM, Reinstalling fresh Windows, Starting in Safe Mode.Local service guy said may be problem with Power IC in motherboard, but he is not sure and replacement will cost me around Rs.3500 approx with no warranty.

Does anyone have similar experience or a solution to this ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Put in DOS"?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry for the misunderstanding. By DOS , I mean the Boot up options for Windows.